# how to import .txt with space in filename

Tags: python-3.x

Code:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines[0:]:
    columns = line.split()
    print(columns[0])
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "scissors.py", line 2, in <module>
        with open (sys.argv[1]) as f:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1'
```

(Links to old images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG1vr.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSpLG.png)

Comment: You need to supply " " around the filename on the commandline:  `python scissors.py "my file with spaces.txt" ` and then you need to delete this rather ill framed question. We do not like pictures of code on SO - we want text we can copy & paste and fix.

Comment: Please add code, not a photo of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Wrap the file name in quotation marks like this `"your file.txt"`
2. If you have a file*path*, use the raw string (and backslashes in the copied filepath) by placing a `r` before the quotation marks:
   `r"C:\Folder\Subfolder\another_one\your_file.txt"`